# Upgrading Acer Aspire 5750G with SSD only boots a single time

Tags: boot, ssd, clone, acer-aspire

I'm currently trying to upgrade the HDD in an Acer Aspire 5750G with a SSD.
Unfortunately I have a weird problem which I've never experienced in the
past (doing SSD upgrades):

I'm cloning the HDD to the SSD (using Paragon Drive copy). After that I mount
the SSD in the Laptop and boot. Everythings works fine and fast.

Now the problem: The next time I switch on the Laptop the SSD is not
recognized anymore. Even in BIOS it is NOT detected.

Removing the SSD and connecting to another system works. That means
The SSD is accessible and everything is in place. Only the Aspire
doesn't recognize it.

Is there any protection or something else built into the BIOS that
makes the SSD "incompatible" to this system?

Comment: Do you do anything special to boot it the first time, cos this sounds A LOT like a BIOS vs EFI issue?

Comment: No I don't do anything special... Right now I'm cloning the HDD to SSD in a separate machine and right after that plug the SSD in the laptop where it is recognized. After shutdown (which windows request due to detecting a change in the drive) it cannot boot anymore. Very weird: It is not even detected by the BIOS anymore.

Answer (score -1):

See you BIOS as the setting to the boot drive or 1st drive must be wrong. SSD drives are different to SATA drives and they must be set on the Aspire differentley.

Comment: How are they different exactly?  A SSD that is compatible with the author's device likely would be a SATA device.  How must it be configured differently?